# Swimming in an enclosed area on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, leniencies, swimming

From what I understand, the shulchan aruch brings down one is not allowed to swim in an open area like around a beach, but what is the opinion of modern poskim on enclosed areas. The local JCC around me has their indoor pool open on Shabbat. Is this allowed?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4833884/jewish/Is-It-OK-to-Swim-on-Shabbat.htm

Comment: Yes, thank you @mbloch